# Why my Alt Tab has become ugly? under Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I don't know why and when it happened, but now, when I use ALT+TAB, it only displays icons of the applications instead of previews.

Also, when I moved the cursor of my mouse in the top left corner of the screen, an overview of all windows was displayed. Now it has no effect anymore.

I think that I might have unintentionally removed a package but I don't know which one.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I reinstalled Nvidia's driver for my GPU in case but it did not fix the problem

Comment: In System Settings > Workspace Appearance and Behavior > Window Behavior > Task Switcher, set the Visualization to something like "Cover Switch" and see if that does anything.

Comment: It didn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Xrender from OpenGL.

I don't know what was the problem with OpenGL. Maybe there were some compatibility issues when I installed Cuda ?